# Error in Qt 6.2.2 source building at final stage, AutoMoc subprocess error

Tags: qt, cmake, build, mingw, qt6

i download qt 6.2.2 source files from qt.io and start to build it according to its ReadMe in windows 10 x64.
in final stage must do

> cmake --build .

to build configured files but it cause error.

```
C:\Qt\Qt6.2.2>cmake --build .

[  0%] Built target BundledLibpng_ext_pri
[  2%] Built target Bootstrap
[  2%] Built target moc
[  2%] Built target Core_lib_pri
[  2%] Built target qmodule_pri
[  2%] Automatic MOC for target Core

AutoMoc subprocess error
------------------------
The moc process failed to compile
  "SRC:/qtbase/src/corelib/animation/qabstractanimation.h"
into
  "SRC:/qtbase/src/corelib/Core_autogen/include/moc_qabstractanimation.cpp"
included by
  "SRC:/qtbase/src/corelib/animation/qabstractanimation.cpp"

Command
-------
C:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/bin/moc.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DPCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH=16 -DPCRE2_STATIC -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_BUILD_CORE_LIB -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS_SINCE=0x060000 -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NO_FOREACH -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -D_UNICODE -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -D_WIN64 -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/corelib -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/include -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/include/QtCore -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/corelib/global -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/tinycbor/src -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/include/QtCore/6.2.2 -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/include/QtCore/6.2.2/QtCore -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/zlib/src -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/double-conversion/double-conversion -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/double-conversion -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/corelib/.rcc -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/mkspecs/win32-g++ -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre2/src -IC:/MinGW/include/c++/11.2.0 -IC:/MinGW/include/c++/11.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -IC:/MinGW/include/c++/11.2.0/backward -IC:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include -IC:/MinGW/include -IC:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include-fixed -IC:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --include C:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/corelib/Core_autogen/moc_predefs.h --output-json --output-dep-file -o C:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/corelib/Core_autogen/include/moc_qabstractanimation.cpp C:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/corelib/animation/qabstractanimation.h

Output
------



AutoMoc subprocess error
------------------------
The moc process failed to compile
  "SRC:/qtbase/src/corelib/animation/qabstractanimation_p.h"
into
  "SRC:/qtbase/src/corelib/Core_autogen/include/moc_qabstractanimation_p.cpp"
included by
  "SRC:/qtbase/src/corelib/animation/qabstractanimation.cpp"

Command
-------
C:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/bin/moc.exe -DCore_EXPORTS -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DPCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH=16 
-DPCRE2_STATIC -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_BUILD_CORE_LIB -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS_SINCE=0x060000 
-DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NO_FOREACH -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DUNICODE 
-DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -D_UNICODE -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -D_WIN64 -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/corelib -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/include -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/include
/QtCore -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/corelib/global -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/tinycbor/src -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/include/QtCore/6.2.2 -IC:/Qt
/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/include/QtCore/6.2.2/QtCore -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/zlib/src -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/double-conversion/double-conversion -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty
/double-conversion -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/corelib/.rcc -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/mkspecs/win32-g++ -IC:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre2/src -IC:/MinGW/include/c++/11.2.0 -IC:/MinGW/include
/c++/11.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -IC:/MinGW/include/c++/11.2.0/backward -IC:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include -IC:/MinGW/include -IC:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include-
fixed -IC:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --include C:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/corelib/Core_autogen/moc_predefs.h --output-json --output-dep-file -o C:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/corelib
/Core_autogen/include/moc_qabstractanimation_p.cpp C:/Qt/Qt6.2.2/qtbase/src/corelib/animation/qabstractanimation_p.h

Output
------


mingw32-make[2]: *** [qtbase\src\corelib\CMakeFiles\Core_autogen.dir\build.make:70: qtbase/src/corelib/CMakeFiles/Core_autogen] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:12102: qtbase/src/corelib/CMakeFiles/Core_autogen.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:145: all] Error 2
```

what should i do with this?
i don't want to install online and must install this offline.